# Can we distinguish direct from transitive partial orders

Tags: order-theory

If I have a set L and a partial order ≤ defined on L, and (L, ≤) is a lattice.
We know that ≤ is transitive, i.e. if

```
l1 ≤ l2 and l2 ≤ l3 then l1 ≤ l3.
```

Well. I need to distinguish those direct ≤ from transitive one. It can be thought as a minimal cover for ≤ on L. Can I make a convention such that:

```
≤d and  ≤t
```

Where ***d*** stands for *direct* and ***t*** stands for *transitive*?
I'm just asking if I can differentiate direct from transitive partial order by using some symbol.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you know about [covers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation) or not. If this isn't what you want, then I can't understand the question.

Comment: No, I meant something else, by minimal cover I mean the minimal set of partial ordered pairs of L, the can produce the whole partially ordered pairs, i.e. it contains no transitive pairs. I'm not sure if I'm misusing the 'cover' idiom. I'm just asking if I can differentiate direct from transitive partial order by using some symbol.